# Php uploading image to server in android

Tags: php, android, server

Im using a php script that allows to choose an image from gallery and upload it to an online web hosting service. The image gets uploaded, but the .jpg file uploaded is empty and is named as 0.jpg and the size is also shown as 0 bytes. when i try to open the image it shows

> "The image http://testimage.site88.net/pic/0.jpg cannot be displayed
>   because it contains errors"

what could be the possible reason for this?
The php code is as follows

```
 <?php
    $name = $_POST['name']; //image name
    $image = $_POST['image']; //image in string format

    //decode the image
    $decodedImage = base64_decode($image);

    //upload the image
    file_put_contents("pic/".$name.".jpg", $decodedImage);
```

the android code is:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    //define global views variable
    public ImageView imageView;
    public Button   selectImage,
                    uploadImage;
    public String SERVER = "http://testimage.site88.net/saveImage.php",
                    timestamp;

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private static final int RESULT_SELECT_IMAGE = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //instantiate view
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        selectImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.selectImage);
        uploadImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.uploadImage);

        //when selectImage button is pressed
        selectImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //call the function to select image from album
                selectImage();
            }
        });

        //when uploadImage button is pressed
        uploadImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //get image in bitmap format
                Bitmap image = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                //execute the async task and upload the image to server
                new Upload(image,"IMG_"+timestamp).execute();
            }
        });

    }

    //function to select a image
    private void selectImage(){
        //open album to select image
        Intent gallaryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(gallaryIntent, RESULT_SELECT_IMAGE);
    }

    /*
    * This function is called when we pick some image from the album
    * */
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == RESULT_SELECT_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null){
            //set the selected image to image variable
            Uri image = data.getData();
            imageView.setImageURI(image);

            //get the current timeStamp and strore that in the time Variable
            Long tsLong = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
            timestamp = tsLong.toString();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),timestamp,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private String hashMapToUrl(HashMap<String, String> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        boolean first = true;
        for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()){
            if (first)
                first = false;
            else
                result.append("&");

            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
            result.append("=");
            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
        }

        return result.toString();
    }


    //async task to upload image
    private class Upload extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>{
        private Bitmap image;
        private String name;

        public Upload(Bitmap image,String name){
            this.image = image;
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            //compress the image to jpg format
            image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,byteArrayOutputStream);
            /*
            * encode image to base64 so that it can be picked by saveImage.php file
            * */
            String encodeImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(),Base64.DEFAULT);

            //generate hashMap to store encodedImage and the name
            HashMap<String,String> detail = new HashMap<>();
            detail.put("name", name);
            detail.put("image", encodeImage);

            try{
                //convert this HashMap to encodedUrl to send to php file
                String dataToSend = hashMapToUrl(detail);
                //make a Http request and send data to saveImage.php file
                String response = Request.post(SERVER,dataToSend);

                //return the response
                return response;

            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e(TAG,"ERROR  "+e);
                return null;
            }
        }



        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            //show image uploaded
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Image Uploaded",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this your real code? With the "&#91;" in it??? Maybe fix that 1st, then try again and while you try it look at the php log, and post what errors you see there in case it doesn't work. Besides you might want to show the android code you used to post the image, as it looks not trivial 'cause you want to send it as a base64 encoded string

Comment: Sorry. Im new to php and i have been looking onto tutorials and found this script. It has this "#91;;" in it. What does that mean.I think it takes the name of the image that has been uploaded and the image will be converted to a string and then to a Base_64. If so, What should replace "#91;;"??

Comment: I don't think timestamp will have a value in onClick. We still don't know what doesn't work. The code looks ok at 1st glance. I fixed your php. Give error messages, details...

Comment: what is the fixed php??

Comment: see ^ in the question

Comment: Also, Im not getting any errors...the whole thing works fine...just when i upload the picture, the picture is named 0.jpg with nothing in theimage

Comment: Actually...i tried that too...but got a different problem

Comment: this time, no image name is there. the file name is just .jpg and nothing in the file when i open it

Comment: add `error_log(print_r($_POST, 1));` as the 2nd line of your php file, and try again, then send the error message from php log

Comment: Wowwwww...worked like a charm!!!!!!!
Thanks a lot for your help......
P.S U're a genius

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just have to fix the php file. I edited it in your question, as it didn't make sense. Use what's there now.

If you need more help, please give us the output of

```
error_log(print_r($_POST, 1));
```

from the php logs.

Comment: If it works now, then read this too: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work